# Checking if property exists using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I'm new in ArcGIS and ArcPy.

I've got f.e. a Layer called "Flurnamen_5000". How can I find out (arcpy) if there exists a "Text Renderers" in `Properties --> Symbologie --> Darstellung (look at the printsceen)`?
[image]
If there is no Text Renderers in the Layer. I'd like to remove the Layer.
I started with:

```
>>> mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
>>> lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Flurnamen_5000")
```

but I have no idea, how to check if a "Text Renderers" exists.

`FeatureType` is simple.

Answer (score 1):

Your ArcMap has a custom extension enabled for your layer. This extension was written with ArcObjects and installed for your ArcGIS Desktop environment. A standard ArcMap does not have the `Text Renderers` option.

As this is a custom property/render type for a layer, you will not be able to access its properties via arcpy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already suspected something like this.

Is it possible to get a list of all key/value pairs of the property dialog (except the custom extension ones)?
f.e. font=Arial or font size=7 or source=.... etc.

Comment: Please ask a separate question on this and we will be glad to help!